# I dont know where to put the intent in a progressbar

Tags: android

here's my java code i've just search on the net. I dont know how i could put and intent in a progressbar so that it could change layout after it loads...if you could help me it would be great...thanks...

```
public class Support extends Activity {
private static int progress;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private int progressStatus = 0;
private Handler handler = new Handler();


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.support);

    progress = 0;
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setMax(400);

    while(progressStatus < 100)
    {
        progressStatus = doSomeWork();
        handler.post(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run(){
                progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);

            }
        });

    }
    handler.post(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            progressBar.setVisibility(0);
        }
    });
```

}

```
private int doSomeWork() {
    try{
        Thread.sleep(50);
}       
catch(InterruptedException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();

}
    return ++progress;
}
```

}

Comment: you want to start other Activity when progressbar complete ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what exactly you want do do, but your while loop is freezing the whole UI. You need to move your loop into an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, that while loop is freezing the UI. You need to move that to a [worker thread or Async Task.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

Second, a progress bar is simply used to show the progress of a lengthy task - not to start an activity. To solve your problem, call `startActivity()` **when the loop finishes**.

Answer (score 0):

## Threading (UI freezing taken care)

### Full XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnStartProgress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Download File" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### Full Code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

Button btnStartProgress;
ProgressDialog progressBar;
private int progressBarStatus = 0;
private Handler progressBarHandler = new Handler();

private long fileSize = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    addListenerOnButton();

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    btnStartProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartProgress);
    btnStartProgress.setOnClickListener(
             new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

        // prepare for a progress bar dialog
        progressBar = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
        progressBar.setCancelable(true);
        progressBar.setMessage("File downloading ...");
        progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        progressBar.show();

        //reset progress bar status
        progressBarStatus = 0;

        //reset filesize
        fileSize = 0;

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            while (progressBarStatus < 100) {

              // process some tasks
              progressBarStatus = doSomeTasks();

              // your computer is too fast, sleep 1 second
              try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }

              // Update the progress bar
              progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                  progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                }
              });
            }

            // ok, file is downloaded,
            if (progressBarStatus >= 100) {

                // sleep 2 seconds, so that you can see the 100%
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // close the progress bar dialog
                progressBar.dismiss();
            }
          }
           }).start();

           }

            });

    }

// file download simulator... a really simple
public int doSomeTasks() {

    while (fileSize <= 1000000) {

        fileSize++;

        if (fileSize == 100000) {
            return 10;
        } else if (fileSize == 200000) {
            return 20;
        } else if (fileSize == 300000) {
            return 30;
        }
        // ...add your own

    }

    return 100;

}

}
```

### Supporting article